# On select value not being passed to php

Tags: php, ajax, variables

I have the following code for my dropbox;

```
<select name="Symptom" id="Symptomid"  onchange="LSC(this.value)">
```

Its options are;

```
 <option value="<?php echo $row_RsSymptom['name']?>"><?php echo     $row_RsSymptom['name']?></option>
```

Full Html Code;

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/Connshifa.php'); ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    mysql_select_db($database_Connshifa, $Connshifa);
    $query_RsSymptom = "SELECT * FROM symptoms ORDER BY symptoms.name";
    $RsSymptom = mysql_query($query_RsSymptom, $Connshifa) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_RsSymptom = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsSymptom);
    $totalRows_RsSymptom = mysql_num_rows($RsSymptom);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Cure by Symptom</title>
    <?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
    ?>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coin-slider.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .main .content .content_resize .mainbar .article label {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-aller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header_resize">
          <div class="slider">
            <div id="coin-slider"></div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content_resize">
          <div class="mainbar">
            <div class="article">
              <h2>Find Your Cure</h2>
              <p class="infopost">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="clr"></div>
              <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="article">
              <h2>Every Disease has a Cure</h2>
    <?php


    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION["username"] . " !" . ".<br>";

    ?> 


              <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">


              <label for="Uname">User Name/Email </label>
                <input name="Uname" type="text" id="Uname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?>" readonly="readonly" />
                <form method="post">
              </form>

                <label for="Symptom"><br />
                  Select your Symptom
                  <br />
                  <br />
                Symptom</label>





                    <?php
    do {  
    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_RsSymptom['name']?>"><?php echo $row_RsSymptom['name']?></option>
                    <?php
    } while ($row_RsSymptom = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsSymptom));
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($RsSymptom);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysql_data_seek($RsSymptom, 0);
          $row_RsSymptom = mysql_fetch_assoc($RsSymptom);
      }
    ?>

                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
    <br />
          <p id="demo"></p>
                    <script>
                        function Symselect() {
                            var x = document.getElementById("Symptomid").value;
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
                        }
           </script>


                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function LSC() {
        // using jquery ajax method for calling the php script
        $.ajax({
            // set this to the url of your php script for calling the LSC function
            url: 'LoadSymptomDetails.php',

            // if the result of the ajax request is ok then this function is called
            success: function(response) {
                // the variable 'response' will contain the output from your php script
                // as an example we'll use a javascript alert to show the output of the response
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>




               <?php

//require("classes\LoadSymptomDetails.php");
            ?>
              <br />
            System</label>
          </form>
          <select name="System" id="System">
          </select>
          <p class="infopost">&nbsp;</p>
          <p class="infopost">&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_resize">
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($RsSymptom);
?>
```

The LoadSymptomDetails.php

```
<?php require_once('Connections/Connshifa.php'); ?>

<?php

//$q = 1

?>

<?php

$data = array();


{
    mysql_select_db("shifa",$Connshifa );

    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name,description , comments
    FROM symptoms WHERE symptoms.name ='".$q."'") or die(mysql_error());

    //$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = '".$q."'";

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
        $data[] = $row1;
    }
}
?>
<?php
if($data){
?>
echo $q
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>comments</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $sy){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sy['name']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $sy['description']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $sy['comments']; ?> </td>

    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
<?php
}

?>


</table>
```

The q is not being picked. If i remove the where statement it runs and displays the table.

Kindly assist.

Azhar

Comment: Please show the rest of the PHP code responsible for getting $_GET['q'] into $q?

Comment: i think it is in the line xmlhttp.open("GET","LoadSymptomDetails.php?q="+str,true); in the script

Comment: Too many unknowns. Meaning, there's too little code to go on here.

Comment: see it works here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp . It doesnt work with my code.

Comment: Just because it works there, doesn't mean that it works here. We don't know if your database contains the same information etc. check for errors and check your console. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php then apply it to your code. There isn't much else I can do here to help you out, sorry.

Comment: i am posting the full code

Answer (score 0):

As we can't see the rest of the PHP, try this for now:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name,description , comments
FROM symptoms WHERE symptoms.name ='".$_GET['q']."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: [`'".$GET_['q']."'"`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33570895/1) that's a syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php - You're putting the horse before the wagon, as it were ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wow, how did you link that code to my first revision? I'd like to do this in the future for usability.

Comment: You may be right, however I find there is too much missing code/information in the question to provide a full solution. I hope this does clear it up, but I have a feeling it won't. I'm not trying rain on your parade here ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- No worries, just trying to offer any assistance I can. He should certainly provide more detailed questions and attempt more things on his end before posting.

Comment: I have now revised and added the full code.                                                $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name,description , comments
FROM symptoms WHERE symptoms.name ='".$_GET['q']."'") or die(mysql_error()); did not work.